# Can't find a JSON file even though they are in the same directory

Tags: python, json, file, path

I'm having a problem opening a JSON file, because it says that is doesn't exists but, it does, it is in the same directory, here, you can see it:

[image]

But even though they are in the same folder, it says that it doesn't exist:

[image]

Here is the code where outputs the error:

```
with open('warn.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    guilds_dict = json.load(f)
    if str(id) in guilds_dict:
        guilds_dict[str(id)] += warns
    else:
        guilds_dict[str(id)] = warns
```

Comment: Are you running the file from the same directory? You have to execute the file from the same dir.

Comment: When you `import os` and print `os.getcwd()` what is returned?

Comment: Did you change your current working directory somewhere in your code? Maybe something you use changes it.

Comment: Change your current working directory or use the absolute path.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Ok thanks, I was that, cause is was executing in other palce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
with open('/root/Nasgar/NasgarBot/cogs/moderation/warn.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    guilds_dict = json.load(f)
    if str(id) in guilds_dict:
        guilds_dict[str(id)] += warns
    else:
        guilds_dict[str(id)] = warns
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing the name.
Secondly, open the file first and then do the other tasks. Check that code is opening your file or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).